# Arquillian Cube and ArquillianResource url

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I have been trying to get the url for my tomcat server(running in a docker container) used in my Junit test and not just localhost.  The reason this is important is my test runs fine locally, but when run on our jenkins node which is also run in Docker, localhost does not work.

I have configued the node to use Docker on Docker configs.  I need the url to use the ip of the parent docker machine.  The odd thing is the jmx url seems to work just fine to deploy the test war, however it is the unit test url itself that has an issue.  I rewrote the test with the ip hard coded and this worked fine, but is really not an optimal solution in the event devs here want to run the test locally.

I also tried using @CubeIp and @DockerUrl or @HostIp, but they either returned just localhost or null, as it says it cannot find the container "tomcat"

Any ideas?

Here is my arquillian.xml

```
<extension qualifier="cube">
    <property name="connectionMode">STARTORCONNECTANDLEAVE</property>

</extension>

<extension qualifier="docker">
    <property name="serverVersion">1.14</property>
    <property name="serverUri">unix:///var/run/docker.sock</property>
    <!--<property name="serverUri">localhost:2375</property>-->
    <property name="dockerInsideDockerResolution">false</property>
    <property name="definitionFormat">CUBE</property>
    <property name="dockerContainersFile">docker-compose.yml</property>
    <property name="dockerRegistry">https://internalnexus.com:5000/</property>
    <property name="username">user</property>
    <property name="password">pass</property>
    <property name="email">email</property>

</extension>

<container qualifier="tomcat" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="host">10.0.20.1</property>
        <property name="httpPort">8080</property>
        <property name="user">user</property>
        <property name="pass">pass</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

And here is my docker compose file

```
`
   tomcat:
        image: internalnexus.com:5000/perf-tomcat:latest
        exposedPorts: [8080/tcp,8089/tcp]
        alwaysPull: false
        await:
          strategy: polling
        env: [TOMCAT_PASS=mypass, JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8089 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dspring.config.location=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/application.properties]
        portBindings: [8089/tcp, 8080/tcp]
        links:
          - database:database
      database:
        image: internalnexus.com:5000/perfstats-sqlserver:latest
        exposedPorts: [1433/tcp]
        env: [SA_PASSWORD=pass, ACCEPT_EULA=Y]
        await:
          strategy: log
          match: 'ms sql server is done'
          stdOut: true
          stdErr: true
          timeout: 30
        portBindings: [1433/tcp]
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one question and it is why you need parent docker host ip?

What I see is that parent docker host ip is the docker host ip where Jenkins node is using. This IP is the one required by external callers to access to Jenkins. Then inside that docker instance you are running another docker host or you are reusing the docker host where Jenkins is running?

Comment: Yes, we are using the "Docker on Docker" setup the the Arquillian Cube documentation references where instead of installing docker on the Jenkins node, you mount the volumes including the docker.sock to use the parent docker instance.  This avoids the "Docker in Docker" issues.  That all is working fine except getting the ip of the parent docker machine where the tomcat container is deployed.  Instead it is using localhost in the test.

Comment: But I don't understand one thing and sorry to insist if you are using docker on docker you are using just one docker host isn't it?

Comment: For what I understand is that you need to communicate with a sibling container not linked isn't it? Jenkins node and Tomcat node are siblings running in same docker host.

Comment: We got it to work, we stopped using the docker.sock and instead set the serverUri property to the ip and port of the docker host parent, then we set host property to dockerServerIp of tomcat container and this substituted the ip from the severUri which was then used in the Junit test instead of localhost.

Comment: Great!!! Just one last thing are you interested in writing an small blog post about it? We can help promoting that.

Comment: sure, what do I need to do?

Comment: Well if you (or company) have a blog post then just write there and we'll help you promote the post. If not you can send a PR to https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube/tree/master/docs and we'll take care of everything :)